# youtube-dl -citw downloads only one video instead of all

Tags: youtube, download, youtube-dl

I used

```
user@ubuntu:~/Arbeitsfläche$ sudo youtube-dl -citw ytuser: raz\ malca
```

to download all videos from this channel. But it wodnloads only one:

```
user@ubuntu:~/Arbeitsfläche$ sudo youtube-dl -citw ytuser: raz\ malca
[generic] ytuser:: Requesting header
ERROR: Invalid URL protocol; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output. Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update.
WARNING: Falling back to youtube search for  raz malca . Set --default-search to "auto" to suppress this warning.
[youtube:search] query "raz malca": Downloading page 1
[download] Downloading playlist: raz malca
[youtube:search] playlist raz malca: Collected 1 video ids (downloading 1 of them)
[download] Downloading video #1 of 1
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] R72vpqqNSDw: Downloading webpage
[youtube] R72vpqqNSDw: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] R72vpqqNSDw: Extracting video information
```

I use the newest version of this programm. 
My system is ubuntu 13.10 :)

Has anyone a idea ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't run youtube-dl with `sudo` - normal user rights suffice. There is also absolutely no need to pass in `-ctw`. But the main problem is that your command line contains a superfluous space after `ytuser:`. In any case, even if the space weren't there, `raz malca` is not a valid YouTube user ID. There is, however, a [channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnmQSqOPhkawAdndZgjfanA) named so. Simply pass in that channel's URL into youtube-dl:

```
youtube-dl -i https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnmQSqOPhkawAdndZgjfanA
```

Answer (score 0):

to find out the channel's URL, do an inspect on the user that created the channel.  E.g. for the channel    mix - o grande amor (Tom Jobim) - Solo Guitar   by Chiba Kosei, right click (in Firefox) on Chiba Kosei and select inspect element.  Notice that the channel is in the href part.  So copy that and your final channel-url is https://youtube.com/channel/UC5q9SrhlCJ4YciPTLLNTR5w

a href="/channel/UC5q9SrhlCJ4YciPTLLNTR5w" class="yt-uix-sessionlink g-hovercard      spf-link " data-ytid="UC5q9SrhlCJ4YciPTLLNTR5w" data-sessionlink="itct=CDIQ4TkiEwjBvtSO7v3KAhWPnr4KHUYMDbko-B0">Chiba Kosei